# Why is systemd-journald doing some massive disk writes?

Tags: io, disk, systemd-journald

For some reason my computer shut down recently. I have also fairly recently done a `pacman -Syu` to upgrade all the things.

However, now `systemd-journald` is doing a *massive* amount of disk writes - like between 50% and 100% as reported by `atop`.

Typically my drive is silent unless I'm spinning up a new process, but right now it's just going and going.

Is there a legitimate reason that `systemd-journald` should be doing so much disk activity? It's been going on for over 10 minutes now.

Comment: Are you able to run the `pidstat` command? It can help show what process is using disk IO. http://sebastien.godard.pagesperso-orange.fr/tutorial.html